# How to prevent accidental deletion in Mongodb Atlas

Tags: mongodb-atlas

Is there a way to prevent accidental deletion of projects and/or clusters in Mongodb Atlas?

I'm coming from AWS where there is such a concept for S3 bucket and RDS databases where you have to manually disable such protection before you can delete the resource.

I've not been able to find an equivalent for Atlas and it makes me a little nervous my team or I could accidentally delete something, especially as we are managing our Atlas infrastructure through Terraform and we could miss something in a `terraform apply`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've just found that Atlas have added this as a new feature when creating a new database of any type (serverless, dedicated, shared):

[image: Termination protection button shown in Atlas UI]

Hopefully will be supported by the Terraform provider soon.